# Angular/cli won't run my ng serve with error in Dart-Sass

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

First time working with `Angular/cli` with a company and I can't access my ng serve in `locathost` and this the error. I have removed and install sass and update `Angular/cli` but still have this error.

> ERROR in ./src/assets/styles/app.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/assets/styles/app.scss)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>   Error: Dart Sass version 1.2.0 is incompatible with ^1.3.0.

Comment: From what version to what did you update the cli?

Comment: Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.1.0

Comment: same issue happening here :/

Answer (score 0):

If it's a nested project, there may be a conflict between your Angular application `node_modules` folder and one on the parent path.